# linux shell date concatenate

Tags: shell, date, concatenation

I want to have filenames with date appended for backup. The error msg is,

test.sh: line 7: ${f}-backup-${date +"%b %e"}.gz: bad substitution

what is wrong? Thanks.

```
FILES=/home/raja/test/*
 for f in $FILES
 do


    echo ${f}-backup-${date +"%b %e"}.gz
 done
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to write `$(date +"%b %e")`. Parenthesis instead of curly braces.

The difference is that `$(...)` creates a subshell which executes `...`, while `${...}` is expanded to the value of `...`.